# Hypergeometric function with changed argument

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, differential-equations, hypergeometric-functions

I have the hypergeometric function $_2F_1 (a, b,c, p\cdot z)$, where $p$ is a parameter and $z$ is the independent variable. I would like to know how the former function is related to the standard hypergeometric function, $_2F_1(a, b,c, z)$, and how to prove that relation.

Comment: It is not clear from your statement what is the dependence on parameter $p$. What does the $*$ mean?

Comment: I edited the statement to make it much more clear. Here $p.z$ is simply the variable $z$ multiplied by a constant called $p$.

Comment: Maybe this link helps: https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F1/23/02/

Answer (score 1):

The relationship can be written using the dilation operator as
$$
_2 F_1 (a,b,c,p\cdot z) = \exp \left( \ln p \cdot z \frac{\partial}{\partial z} \right)\, {}_2 F_1 (a,b,c,z)
$$